# What exactly does `inner sep` mean when node shape is circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

`inner sep` is not behaving as I would expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]

  \coordinate (P1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (P2) at ($(P1)+(30:2cm)$);

  %% first circle
  %% separation along x-, y- directions is greater than 2cm.
  \node [inner sep=2cm,orange,line width=3pt] at (P1) {};        

  %% second circle
  %% separation along x-, y- directions is as expected
  \node [inner xsep=2cm,blue!30,line width=2pt] at (P1) {};        

  %% third circle
  %% duplicates the situation of the first circle.  Again
  %% the separation along axes is greater than expected.
  \node [inner xsep=2cm,
         inner ysep=2cm,yellow,line width=1pt] at (P1) {};        

  \draw (P1) circle [radius=2cm,draw,magenta];        

  \draw (P1) -- (P2);

  \draw[help lines] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the documentation on `inner sep`, `inner xsep`, `inner ysep` I would expect the distance to be measured using a Euclidean metric and not a Taxi cab metric.

Can someone explain what's happening here?  Why is this the desired behavior

Comment: If you declare `inner sep=<length>`, the radius of the circle will be `<length>*\sqrt{2}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Exactly.  However, that doesn't seem to be made very clear in the documentation.  But more importantly, I'm curious why it works this way.

Comment: I suppose if you consider a node as a rectangular text block with some path drawn around it, it makes sense, you need a circle of that size to circumscribe the rectangle. For each of your three cases, add a node identical to the one you have, but add the `rectangle` option.

Answer (score 7):

The `circle` shape is the circumscribed circle to the standard `rectangle` shape.
So, if you want that this circle to be with radius 2cm, you have to put one length of the rectangle to 2cm and the other to 0cm.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, very thick}]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P1) +(30:2cm) coordinate (P2);

  %% first circle
  %% fitting square 2cmx2cm
  \node [inner sep=2cm, green] at (P1) {};
  \node [circle, inner sep=2cm, green] at (P1) {};

  %% second circle
  %% fitting square 2cmx0cm
  \node [inner xsep=2cm, inner ysep=0cm, red] at (P1) {};
  \node [circle, inner xsep=0cm, inner ysep=2cm, red] at (P1) {};

  \draw (P1) circle [radius=2cm, draw, magenta];

  \draw (P1) -- (P2);

  \draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT :** I came to see the comment from  Torbjørn T. which says exactly the same thing. Sorry for the duplicate.