# `inner sep` of TikZ has a negative limit?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I normally use a negative `inner sep` to shrink a white-filled node to cover a line behind some text, but when I tried to use it with some long text, it stops getting smaller and starts growing again. (*First set* and *Second set*)

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218398/142706) that explains how `inner sep` behaves on `circle` and I could solve the problem using both `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` together. (*Third set*)

I understand that `inner sep` becomes so negative that it inverts itself and starts growing again. But the question is:

**why doesn't `inner sep` go to zero-radius before growing again?**

---

**Note:** I am aware that there are many ways to work around this problem, but to use `inner sep` is more practical for me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [ My Style/.style={circle, draw, fill=white} ]

    % Vertical lines
    \draw   (0,2) -- (0,-8)
            (3,2) -- (3,-8)
            (6,2) -- (6,-8);

    % First horizontal set (normal behavior)
    \node[My Style,                ] at (0,0)  {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=0pt  ] at (3,0)  {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-10pt] at (6,0)  {long long text};

    % Second horizontal set ('inner sep' stops shrinking)
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-15pt] at (0,-3) {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-20pt] at (3,-3) {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-30pt] at (6,-3) {long long text};

    % Third horizontal set (solved with both 'inner xsep' and ' inner ysep')
    \node[My Style, inner xsep=-30pt, inner ysep=-4pt] at (0,-5) {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner xsep=-30pt, inner ysep=-10pt] at (3,-5) {long long text};
    \node[My Style, inner xsep=-40pt, inner ysep=-10pt] at (6,-5) {long long text};


    % Fourth horizontal set (small text or no text)
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-5pt] at (0,-7) {text};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-0pt] at (3,-7) {};
    \node[My Style, inner sep=-5pt] at (6,-7) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the inner sep is not acting on the circle directly but it acts on a rectangle inside the circle -- the rectangle has the four corners touching the circle on its inside on the  perimeter -- the negative values would thus start a rectangle on the opposite side and hence no dot or as desired no zero value  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554230/197451

Comment: As there are `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`, I concluded that `inner sep` should behave like some kind of diagonal, so I thought it was strange not to get a zero-radius circle (or rectangle). However, it seems that the inner rectangle turns into a line and then starts growing again, like you said.